# Correction values in array with condition and save the output with Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have dataset in 3 columns [lat,lon,tem] under "Data.dat" but the temp must be corrected to some value at some condition. Currently, the script not allowing the correction to happen.

```
data=np.loadtxt('Data.dat')
lats=data[:,0]
lons=data[:,1]
tirs=data[:,2]

## condition
for x in tirs:
    if x < 220:
        lons2=lons+0.05
    else:
        lons2=lons
data_new=np.array([lats,lons,tirs,lons2])
data_new=np.transpose(data_new)

np.savetxt('Data_New.dat',data_new,fmt='%9.3f')
```

The data "Data.dat" as follows;

```
0.200   112.150   250.100
0.250   112.100   241.440
0.250   112.100   241.440
0.250   112.050   242.520
0.300   112.000   242.520
0.000   112.650   232.700
0.050   112.600   216.670
0.050   112.600   216.670
0.050   112.550   211.650
0.100   112.500   212.750
0.100   112.450   216.750
0.150   112.400   221.780
0.150   112.400   221.780
0.150   112.350   238.300
0.200   112.300   236.940
0.200   112.250   248.110
```

Whenever the temp <220 the respective lons will be added 0.05 to the current lons.
Expected output is as follows:

```
0.200   112.150   250.100   112.150
0.250   112.100   241.440   112.100
0.250   112.100   241.440   112.100
0.250   112.050   242.520   112.050
0.300   112.000   242.520   112.000
0.000   112.650   232.700   112.650
0.050   112.600   216.670   112.650
0.050   112.600   216.670   112.650
0.050   112.550   211.650   112.600
0.100   112.500   212.750   112.550
0.100   112.450   216.750   112.500
0.150   112.400   221.780   112.400
0.150   112.400   221.780   112.400
0.150   112.350   238.300   112.350
0.200   112.300   236.940   112.300
0.200   112.250   248.110   112.250
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You expect another column to be added, instead of the existing values being updated? Also, what's your current output?

Comment: @JanWilamowski it was unchanged. still follow the original data in lons